# Regex to list all rows

Tags: regex, sh

I have the following text and if you look carefully there are two rows of BuildType_Decorated. I'm trying to create a regex to list all rows but I don't get it :(

This is my temp.txt file.

> [BuildType_Decorated{name=debug, debuggable=true,
> testCoverageEnabled=false, jniDebuggable=false,
> pseudoLocalesEnabled=false, renderscriptDebuggable=false,
> renderscriptOptimLevel=3, minifyEnabled=false, zipAlignEnabled=true,
> signingConfig=SigningConfig_Decorated{name=debug,
> storeFile=/mypath/debug.keystore, storePassword=android,
> keyAlias=AndroidDebugKey, keyPassword=android, storeType=jks,
> v1SigningEnabled=true, v2SigningEnabled=true,
> v1SigningConfigured=false, v2SigningConfigured=false},
> embedMicroApp=false, mBuildConfigFields={}, mResValues={},
> mProguardFiles=[], mConsumerProguardFiles=[],
> mManifestPlaceholders={}}, BuildType_Decorated{name=release,
> debuggable=false, testCoverageEnabled=false, jniDebuggable=false,
> pseudoLocalesEnabled=false, renderscriptDebuggable=false,
> renderscriptOptimLevel=3, minifyEnabled=false, zipAlignEnabled=true,
> signingConfig=null, embedMicroApp=true, mBuildConfigFields={},
> mResValues={},
> mProguardFiles=[/mypath/path/proguard-android-optimize.txt-4.1.1,
> /mypath/path/proguard-rules.pro], mConsumerProguardFiles=[],
> mManifestPlaceholders={}}]

This is what I have so far.

```
^(BuildType_Decorated{).*(},)$
```

## Update

I've just wrote this script but I'm unable to print the two rows(one after each other).

```
#!/bin/sh
value=`cat temp.txt`
valueWOBegin=`echo ${value/*====BUILDTYPES====/}`
valueWOEnd=`echo ${valueWOBegin/====END BUILDTYPES====*/}`
for string in "$(echo $valueWOEnd | grep -Po "((BuildType_Decorated).+?((?=, BuildType_Decorated)|(?=]$)))")"; do
    echo $string
done
```

Comment: Use `grep -oP 'BuildType_Decorated{.*?},' file` (see [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uEzmkE/1))

Comment: I've tried but looks like -oP flags are not valid using grep.

Comment: Install the `pcregrep` and use the pattern above with it. Also, you might try `pcregrep -o 'BuildType_Decorated({(?:[^{}]++|(?1))*})'`, or use Cacahuet's regex with the tool.

Comment: Actually, you have two. Use `echo "$string"` and `echo "$valueWOEnd"`.

Comment: echo "$string" just prints one row, i mean it only prints one iteration, actually the whole text.

Comment: Acrtually, there are 2, see https://rextester.com/MVC99668

Comment: I've updated my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this ?

```
((BuildType_Decorated).+?((?=, BuildType_Decorated)|(?=]$)))
```

But actually you may use an other method than regex, json or something...

**RESPONSE TO UPDATE**

```
#!/bin/bash

grep -Po "((BuildType_Decorated).+?((?=, BuildType_Decorated)|(?=]$)))" temp.txt | while read -r line ; do
    echo "$line"
    echo -e '--------\n'
done
```

Comment: Hi, I've updated my question. Could you help me?

Answer (score 2):

You may use this `gnu-awk`:

```sh
awk -v RS='\\[?BuildType_Decorated' 'NF{ print prt $0 } { prt = RT }' file

[BuildType_Decorated{name=debug, debuggable=true, testCoverageEnabled=false, jniDebuggable=false, pseudoLocalesEnabled=false, renderscriptDebuggable=false, renderscriptOptimLevel=3, minifyEnabled=false, zipAlignEnabled=true, signingConfig=SigningConfig_Decorated{name=debug, storeFile=/mypath/debug.keystore, storePassword=android, keyAlias=AndroidDebugKey, keyPassword=android, storeType=jks, v1SigningEnabled=true, v2SigningEnabled=true, v1SigningConfigured=false, v2SigningConfigured=false}, embedMicroApp=false, mBuildConfigFields={}, mResValues={}, mProguardFiles=[], mConsumerProguardFiles=[], mManifestPlaceholders={}},
BuildType_Decorated{name=release, debuggable=false, testCoverageEnabled=false, jniDebuggable=false, pseudoLocalesEnabled=false, renderscriptDebuggable=false, renderscriptOptimLevel=3, minifyEnabled=false, zipAlignEnabled=true, signingConfig=null, embedMicroApp=true, mBuildConfigFields={}, mResValues={}, mProguardFiles=[/mypath/path/proguard-android-optimize.txt-4.1.1, /mypath/path/proguard-rules.pro], mConsumerProguardFiles=[], mManifestPlaceholders={}}]
```